# What is the best approach in React Application for the case without using Redux?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to submit data via an api on a click of button in the parent Component, on collecting data from multiple sub components in different hierarchy.

I have a discussion on the case with one of my colleague and he suggest me to have a method in a parent comp. and share that (as a handler) to child(s) in prop and then to further to its child(s), keeping child comp. as stateless comp. Such that when user inputs the data it will store into a **state** variable (in parent comp.) via that handler method. For e.g:

```js
class Parent extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    this.state.data = {}
  }

  updateHndler(key, value){
    this.setState({
       data : {...this.setState.data, key: value}
    })
  }
}

const ChildA = props => {
  onComplete(e){
    this.props.updateHndler('text', e.target.value)
  }

  return (<div>
     ...
     ..
     <input .. onChange={()=>{onComplete(e)}}
  </div>)
}
```

As each sub-component setting the value in parent state variable for each value it is getting update and its render() method keeps trigger, considering the rendering cost for all the sub-components on each change is the above approach is even good enough?

Thanks

Comment: Presumably the `Parent` component needs to keep the value in its state so in that case is this really avoidable?

Comment: I think it's not the best solution, I can recommend for use React Hooks, like useContext

Comment: you can always use rxjs without using redux.. so you can create an observable where the parent component will subscribe for new values and the child components emit new subjects.

Comment: The rendering cost for sub-components should be minimal, as React's change detection should work pretty well in your case. It will only trigger actual DOM re-renders when actual data have changed.

Comment: will check for React Hooks, @itdoesntwork good one, but is it good to update the state variable of parent (includes nth childs) as in case parent state update it will call its render method so child component will re-render also!

Comment: There's nothing wrong with this approach, you're storing the state in a parent container component instead of an immutable store. It's not clear why redux is not an option or what you're trying to achieve, so it's difficult to address your specific concerns.

Comment: Well redux is not mandatory.. you can build applications without using it. If you have a case that you don't want to rerender all the time you can overwrite the 'shouldComponentUpdate' method.. https://lucybain.com/blog/2017/react-js-when-to-rerender/

Comment: @JimEdelstein my concern is, render() calls whenever this.setState() gets call and when render of the parent call it will be be calling render of each sub-component, and lets, if keeping shouldComponentUpdate to false, then shouldComponentUpdate will call for each sub-comp. so in this contrast is the solution is good enough or is there any better approach to the above case, thats all.

Comment: also besides the performance I have to attach (or pass) that handler to each of the component as a props which is also not consider to be that much good, i believe!

Comment: furthermore the value I like to store is not for managing app state but collecting data for the apiCall.

Comment: @smkrn110 if you're experiencing render performance issues then shouldComponentUpdate overrides is the way to go.  Passing the one function around so all components are using the same function to update state, and storing that state in the parent container isn't so bad.  Your concerns are what tools like redux were designed to address.  That being said, unless you are certain you have rendering performance issues I'd warn against over optimizing.  How many subcomponents do you anticipate?